# Put value from a mysql databae-generated dropdown list into a form input field

Tags: php, forms, input

I have a dropdown list populated from a database query. Options are 1, 2, 3, etc. When an item is selected, I want the value of the comp_id (for example "1") to go in the placeholder of an input field of a form. When the form is submitted, the value of the placeholder will then be inserted in another table in the database (together with other data) via an INSERT statement. This is my code:

```
<?php
    echo "<label>Please select the Competition:&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name='opt'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {            
    echo "<option value='" . $row['comp_id'] ."'>" . $row['compname'] ."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select></label>";
    print_r($row['comp_id']);
    ?>
```

And this is part of the form:

```
<input type="text" name="comp_id" placeholder=" (the value from the selected item ">
```

I can't seem to find a solution despite the countless searches I have made. Very grateful for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

**HTML**

```
<select name="opt">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="comp_id" placeholder="(the value from the selected item)">
```

**jQuery**

```
$("select[name=opt]").on("change", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
  $("input[name=comp_id]").attr( "placeholder", val );
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/naveed/eksz5nd7/1/)

***Note:*** Only values of input fields will be posted on form submission. Placeholders will not be posted on form submission.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But as I said, my list is populated from a database using php. How can I apply your jQuery proposal please, if it can be done?